# Trying to use VBA macro to paste a formula to the selected cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a macro that will paste a simple formula to add zeros on the cells that I select. This is what I have but it only works on the defined cells and I am not sure how to change the cell address to work on whatever cells the user selects.

```
Sub TimeConversion()
  ActiveCell.Formula = "=REPT(0,4-LEN(E8)) & E8" 
End Sub
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I just need to be able to select various cells and run the REPT formula on them.

Thank you!

Comment: Can they only select cells where you want a formula? Will you expect them to select other cells in the same sheet and no formula to appear?

Answer (score 2):

A basic principle would be to use a worksheet_SelectionChange event but you will probably want to restrict to certain cells as otherwise, any cell you select in the sheet which has the event will get the formula. Thanks to @GMalc for clarifying requirement and offering an amendment.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
     Target.NumberFormat = "0000"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You can use Intersect and a specified range to limit to certain cells.

The code goes in the code pane of the sheet you want the formulas to appear in. Not in a standard | class module.

Comment: I am trying to use this however now I get the error that "The macro may not be available in this workbook" I know you said this goes in the code pane but I'm not really sure what you mean. The formula bar?

Comment: Select the actual worksheet tab in the workbook and right click view code > it goes in that window. The one associated with a specific sheet

Comment: Ok I see, I did that and I am still not getting the desired result. I need to be able to run this on various sheets and cells. Is there any way to set this up as a standard macro that can be invoked on any cells on any workbook? Thank you for you help by the way. I am pretty lost on this right now.

Comment: There are ways. You can insert that code in each sheet but there is also a way using ThisWorkbook I believe. There is an answer on SO detailing this. If I can find it I will dig it out or someone else may chip in with a solution.

Comment: @QHarr i think he wants to add four zeros to values to whatever cell/s he selects, he want to make `E8` any cell he selects, not `E8`. If he wants to use a formula he will have to have a helper row, but i think he wants a macro.

Comment: @GMalc Oops... so not always E8? So concatente in target.address if single cell

Comment: how about this; `Selection.NumberFormat = "0000"`

Comment: @GMalc  if you want to put that as an answer I would be happy to delete this.

Comment: Your macro is better than my simple one, but i added it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This macro will add four zeros to the select cell/s.

```
For Each cell In Selection
    cell.NumberFormat = "@"
    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", 4) & cell
Next
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. Here is my final strip of code. I have to do this because the standard formatting does work properly for 24 hour time for some reason. Sub TimeConversion()
For Each cell In Selection
    cell.NumberFormat = "@"
    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", 4 - Len(cell)) & cell
    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Replace(cell, 3, 0, ":")
Next
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking out for a Solution in `Excel-Formula` applied in `Excel-VBA`, then here it is..

```
Sub test()
ActiveCell.Formula = "=REPT(0,4-LEN(E" & ActiveCell.Row & "))& E" & ActiveCell.Row & ""
End Sub
```